# problem with select boxes - second options based on first selection

Tags: javascript, select, window.open

I just posted a question about opening in a new window but if I use window.location it doesn't work?? is there a problem with my javascript?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function setOptions(chosen){

var selbox = document.formName.table;
selbox.options.length = 0;

if (chosen == " ") {
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('No diploma selected',' ');
 }
if (chosen == "1") {
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option one','http://www.pitman-training.com');
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option two','onetwo');
 }
if (chosen == "2") {
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option one','twoone');
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option two','twotwo');
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option three','twothree');
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option four','twofour');
 }
if (chosen == "3") {
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option one','threeone');
 selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option two','threetwo');
 }
}

</script>
```

Its a little messy I know...

```
<form name="formName" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.formName.optone.options[document.formName.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
 <option value=" " selected="selected">Please select a diploma</option>
 <option value="1">First Choice</option>
 <option value="2">Second Choice</option>
 <option value="3">Third Choice</option>
</select>

<select name="table" size="1" >
 <option value=" " selected="selected">No diploma selected</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" onclick="ob=this.form.table;window.location(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value)"/>


</form>
```

to be honest I'm not happy with this anyway I want a way to hide the Submit button until the second selected box has been selected...but I'm no java expert! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're saying you want it in a new window or not, so...

If you want a new window then

```
window.open(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value)
```

If you want the same window then

```
window.location = ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions.

- You should capture the `onsubmit` event of your form rather than the `onclick` event of your submit button.  Forms can be submitted without using the button (for example, pressing enter) so your onclick event would miss this.
- You can use the `window.open(url)` function to open a new window.
- Rather than hiding the input button (which won't stop keyboard users from submitting the form), in the onsubmit event ensure the options are selected and `return false;` if they aren't.
- You can neaten and speed up your code by not making so many lookups on element objects.
- Use `this` inside an event handler attribute to get a handle to the firing element e.g.  `<select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">`

Example:

```
document.formName.table.onsubmit = function ()
{
    if (this.table.selectedIndex == 0 && this.optone.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        // This is just an example. Showing a div would be better than alert();
        alert("You haven't filled in the required elements");

        // Cancel submission by returning false
        return false;
    }
    ob=this.table;

    // Open a new window and go to URL:
    window.open(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value);

    // Go to URL in current window:
    // window.location = ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value;
}
function setOptions(chosen){       
    var selbox  = document.formName.table;
    var options = selbox.options;
    var cOpt    = options.length = 0; 

    if (chosen == " ") { 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('No diploma selected',' '); 
    } 
    else if (chosen == "1") { 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('first choice - option one','http://www.pitman-training.com'); 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('first choice - option two','onetwo'); 
    } 
    else if (chosen == "2") { 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('second choice - option one','twoone'); 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('second choice - option two','twotwo'); 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('second choice - option three','twothree'); 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('second choice - option four','twofour'); 
    } 
    else if (chosen == "3") { 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('third choice - option one','threeone'); 
        options[cOpt++] = new Option('third choice - option two','threetwo'); 
    } 
}
```

Always use `else if` where applicable and try to reduce lookups to DOM nodes and their properties (such as `selbox.options.length`).  `cOpt++` will let us use the current value of `cOpt` and then increment it by 1, so you don't need to keep checking the length of `selbox.options`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Andy, I can't get it to work though... it doesn't actually do anything? if I hit submit it just reloads the form... (i'm only trying first choice option one)

Comment: @Charles Marsh: Try adding `return false;` at the end of the `onsubmit` event to stop the page from reloading.